# SQLiteDatabaseHelper receiving IllegalStateException: database not open in constructor

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I cleared out my applications data to test creating a new table, but whenever I call `getWritableDatabase` from my subclass `SQLiteDatabaseHelper`, I'm getting an `IllegalStateException: database not open`.

I don't understand why I would be getting a 'database not open' when I'm trying to open the database...

Here's my home activity onCreate:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    mPhotoArr = new ArrayList<File>();

    DBHelper dbHelp = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());
}
```

And the beginning of the constructor for my DBHelper class

```
public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, "MyDatabase", null, 1);
    db = getWritableDatabase(); //Crashing here
    ...
```

The callstack is:

```
06-16 22:01:07.113: E/AndroidRuntime(24970): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-16 22:01:07.113: E/AndroidRuntime(24970): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{**package**/**package**HomeActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: database not open
06-16 22:01:07.113: E/AndroidRuntime(24970):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
06-16 22:01:07.113: E/AndroidRuntime(24970):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
06-16 22:01:07.113: E/AndroidRuntime(24970):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
06-16 22:01:07.113: E/AndroidRuntime(24970):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
06-16 22:01:07.113: E/AndroidRuntime(24970):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-16 22:01:07.113: E/AndroidRuntime(24970):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-16 22:01:07.113: E/AndroidRuntime(24970):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
06-16 22:01:07.113: E/AndroidRuntime(24970):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-16 22:01:07.113: E/AndroidRuntime(24970):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-16 22:01:07.113: E/AndroidRuntime(24970):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
06-16 22:01:07.113: E/AndroidRuntime(24970):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
06-16 22:01:07.113: E/AndroidRuntime(24970):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-16 22:01:07.113: E/AndroidRuntime(24970): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: database not open
06-16 22:01:07.113: E/AndroidRuntime(24970):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.endTransaction(SQLiteDatabase.java:555)
06-16 22:01:07.113: E/AndroidRuntime(24970):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:137)
06-16 22:01:07.113: E/AndroidRuntime(24970):    at **package**.DBHelper.<init>(DBHelper.java:101)
06-16 22:01:07.113: E/AndroidRuntime(24970):    at **package**.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:53)
06-16 22:01:07.113: E/AndroidRuntime(24970):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-16 22:01:07.113: E/AndroidRuntime(24970):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
06-16 22:01:07.113: E/AndroidRuntime(24970):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: `getWritableDatabase()` has to be surrounded by try/catch or have the function throw and excemption. Also, more importantly, `getWritableDatabase()` RETURNS a database object, which is what is used to access the database.

Comment: @LuckyMe Added db = getWritableDatabase(). I agree I should have a try/catch, but still - why would simply trying to get a database object result in an exception saying the database isn't open? Isn't the point of getReadable/WritableDatabase to open it?

Comment: You're extending SQLiteOpenHelper, right?

Comment: @Don Correct. I'm starting to think my class is far too hacked together.. I'm actually surprised it worked at all. I've been opening / closing instances of the database all over the place, recursive getWritableDatabase calls.. etc. 

Would it be best practice to open and close a Database object as needed for executing sql statements? Or should I be setting a local SQLiteDatabase variable to a writable database and leaving it open indefinitely? I may go through the entire class and clean it all up.

Comment: I had to use a database for one of my applications. I used a custom class that I called DataSource to manage my database operations. You may or may not need to do something like this - it all depends on how much reading / writing you're going to be doing to the database. If you do want to create a DataSource class to manage your database operations, there's a great tutorial here: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html Also, I'm pretty sure that I know why you're getting this error. I'll post an answer.

Comment: To answer your question from your comment, doing all of that opening and closing on the database isn't the best performance wise. I create a connection to the database (via my DataSource class) when the Activity / Fragment is created, call open on my database (again via my DataSource class) when I need to read or write, and then close the database when my Activity closes.

Comment: Not to mention, if you're doing this on the UI thread, you're application is going to lag and be unresponsive.

Comment: @Don Loving the DataSource idea, I just found that link actually. I'm definitely going to follow your advice of leaving it open for the activity. In going through my class, I've been opening and closing for almost every method (called multiple times per activity). That's what I get for hacking together one of my core classes without fully understanding the architecture behind it :)

Comment: Haha ya. Databases can get pretty messy.

Comment: Note to add: create a database package and put all of your database access there, limit the access to the database to that package, that way if you want to do any changes, you can just do it there and not worry about other places having access. I have one main static class inside the database package which I make calls through it. and that class does all the connections and stuff.

Comment: @LuckyMe Exactly what I was looking into - a static class to manage the database, especially since I have a few classes that might be trying to work with the database. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use a custom DataSource helper class, then I would go about getting a reference to your database like this: create a reference to your custom class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper, and then call `myReferenceToSQLiteOpenHelper.getWriteableDatabase()` and store this in a SQLiteOpenHelper reference in your activity. After that, you can do whatever operations you need. Just make sure that you close the database when you're finished.

Like this:

```
MySQLiteOpenHelper mHelper = new MySQLiteOpenHelper(context);
SQLiteOpenHelper sHelper = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
```

Comment: Yep - found it. The onCreate was being given an SQLiteDatabase object (already open) since it was the applications first run and needed to create my tables, but I had a function being called from onCreate that kept trying to open it's own connection. Not sure why I was getting a "database not open" instead of a recursive call. Passed in the database object to that function and it cleared right up. Will be rethinking my database class as in the comments. Much thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Adding what I ended up doing for anyone else who might find this question. I created a subclass of Application per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708012/android-how-to-declare-global-variables) answer to hold my database helper. Whenever I have an activity or DAO within an activity that needs to query my database, the activity is created with a subclass of Activity for easier retrieval of the database.

Note that this does work when using ActionBar Sherlock - you just need to subclass the appropriate ABS activity.